# google map marker infoWindow with html tag and css style

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i am trying to add details along with html tag but for some reason my tags inside infowindow not recognized. I have stored div tags with address in "contentString". I have declare infowindow variable global and in my initializeMap function i declare  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

many thanks in advance ...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': marker.getPosition() }, function (results, status) {

   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

       var address = results[1].formatted_address;

       var contentString = '<div>' + address + '<div>';

       infowindow.setContent(contentString);

       infowindow.open(map, this);
   }

 });
});
```

Comment: you have error with the closing `<div>` tag : should be `</div>`

Comment: this is not complete; you don't show how you create the infoWindow. please should your complete code in jsfiddle.

Comment: @toxic are you able to open the infoWindow?

Comment: i had tryied before with proper /div tag but miss out here ... however thanks for solution ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly because `this` is a not the marker? Try to use `that`:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    var that = this;
    ...
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': marker.getPosition() }, function (results, status) {
        ...
        infowindow.open(map, that);
    });
});
```

Comment: many thanks Tomas it works...  it worried i didn't really get that as i am using same maker to get latLong coordinates ... !

Comment: @toxic you may use the same marker but who knows how the `this` is set in the function you pass to geocode... if my workaround works, it is because of that `this` ;-) this is a common mistake

Answer (score 0):

complete function to create marker that i am calling with each service that comes back from nearBySearch result.

```
function createMarker(place) {

var IconType = {
   school: "../Icons/google_school.png",
   university: "../Icons/university.png",
};

var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: placeLoc,
    icon: IconType[place.types[0]]
});

markers.push(marker);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

var that = this;

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': marker.getPosition() }, function (results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

             var address = results[0].formatted_address;

   var infoWindow_content = '<div class="google_infoBlock">'+
                            '<div class="google_info_Title">' + place.name + '</div>'+
                            '<div class="google_info_address">' + address + '</div>' +
                            '</div>';

        infowindow.setContent(infoWindow_content);

        infowindow.open(map, that);
    }           
  });
 });
}
```

### info block css

```
.google_infoBlock {
   font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;    
}

.google_info_Title {
   color:#B0171F;
   font-size:16px;
 }

.google_info_address {
    color:#3d3d3d;
    font-size:14px;
}
```